# Angular.js- Using ._extend() to extend a base Directive- How to replace Directive name?

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

I wrote a custom base directive. I will be using this base directive for other directives...for instance, I will write a directive for `deleteButton` and attach it to `baseConfirmation`.

I could use just use Angular.js directive inheritance, and have `deleteButton` require `baseConfirmation`. But I would like to use underscore's `_.extend()` because it would be cleaner to have something like
`_.extend(deleteButtonDirective, baseConfirmation, templateUrl: '/new/url/template);`

But the issue is, since `.directive('baseConfirmation'` is not a object...not sure how I would replace this name. I would need to replace the directive name to `deleteButtonDirective`. Is this possible with _.extend()?

```
angular.module('main.vips').directive('baseConfirmation',
    function($modal) {
        var confirmModal = function(theScope) {
            return $modal.open({
                templateUrl: '../confirm_modal.html',
                scope: theScope,
                backdrop: false
            });
        }
      return {
        templateUrl: ,
        restrict: "AE",
        scope: {
          'iconAttribute': "@",
        },
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            var modalInstance;
            $scope.commentBox = {};

            function modalWork() {
                modalInstance.result.then(function() {
                    //if promise is fullfilled
                    console.log($scope.commentBox.text);
                }, function() {
                    //if promise is deferred/rejected
                    console.log("Canceled")
                })
                .finally(function() {
                    $scope.commentBox.text = "";
                });
            }
            $scope.cancel = function() {
                modalInstance.dismiss();
                modalWork();
            }
            $scope.ok = function() {
                modalInstance.close();
                modalWork();
            }
            $element.on("click", function(event) {
                modalInstance = confirmModal($scope);
            });
        }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be incredibly difficult to do - you need to deal with more than just the fact that a Directive isn't a simple object. There is also a cache layer involved that will probably break what you do even if you get it hooked up.

Pawel Gerr recently blogged about an interesting technique for creating 'Dynamic Directives' and he has solutions for these issues in his post, as well as a jsFiddle illustrating his technique. I'm not comfortable doing something like this in my own projects (his technique or yours) because when you start working around frameworks like this and voiding their core philosophies, you'll never know which upcoming release will break your code. I actually think directive inheritance is a pretty good answer, and you won't have a sword hanging over your hand in the future... But if you're determined to do this it's definitely an interesting read! :)

http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/pawel/2014/07/angularjs-dynamic-directives.html